# How to run a single deploy when Travis builds succeeds?

Tags: python, travis-ci

I am running Travis CI using matrix of Python versions but I do want to execute the release actions only after all of these are passed, obviously.

How can I do this? It seems that the "deploy" actions are executed for each sub-build.

Comment: I think this is currently not possible. What kind of deployment do you have in mind?

Comment: something is wrong if this is not possible, I am trying to deploy the package to pypi, i cannot deploy several times and i do not want to deploy if one build fails...

Comment: Yes, it's a reasonable to have such a feature, especially for things like pypi/npm etc. where it actually should work for several releases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that this is not currently possible and there is a bug tracking it at:
https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/929

Update

Travis disables commenting on that issue which is really a bad thing. I guess you only option now is to tweet them to reopen it. Use social pressure, works against closed business models! ;)

Also if you happen to know some competitors that do allow this, mention them! ... in the same tweet.

Comment: FYI, Build Stages have been added to Travis CI as a beta feature which should allow you to accomplish what you wanted: https://blog.travis-ci.com/2017-05-11-introducing-build-stages

Answer (score 3):

It is possible by using bash and Travis built-in variables. For a JavaScript / Node repo that would be:

```
dist: trusty
language: node_js
node_js:
  - '8'
  - '7'
install: ...
script: ...
after_success:
  - 'if [ "${TRAVIS_NODE_VERSION}" = "8" ]; then cat ./coverage/lcov.info | coveralls ; fi'
  - 'if [ "${TRAVIS_NODE_VERSION}" = "8" ]; then firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN --non-interactive ; fi'
```

Other built-in variables:

- `TRAVIS_DART_VERSION`
- `TRAVIS_GO_VERSION`
- `TRAVIS_HAXE_VERSION`
- `TRAVIS_JDK_VERSION`
- `TRAVIS_JULIA_VERSION`
- `TRAVIS_NODE_VERSION`
- `TRAVIS_OTP_RELEASE`
- `TRAVIS_PERL_VERSION`
- `TRAVIS_PHP_VERSION`
- `TRAVIS_PYTHON_VERSION`
- `TRAVIS_R_VERSION`
- `TRAVIS_RUBY_VERSION`
- `TRAVIS_RUST_VERSION`
- `TRAVIS_SCALA_VERSION`

See https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/

---

Credits to [@airbnb/enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/.travis.yml) which is where I took the idea from.